# #Error in report trying to set Textbox value to global var

Tags: navision

I'm trying to set my global var MyReportTitle value to my textbox in a report. But when printing the report, it appears #Error.

I create a global var name MyReportTitle and depending of a boolean called proforma, i define a Report Title.

[image]

I'm receiving the value of my global in the message, like the image below but why is not showing in report?

[image]

I set the textbox expression to =Globals!MyReportTitle.Value

Answer (score 0):

Globals!MyReportTitle is not equals with the ReportTitle from you dataset.
You need to reference ReporTitle (from NAV) same as the other fields